# How to dummify with one row per ID and multple dummies == 1?

Tags: r, dplyr, dummy-variable

I've been working in something related to the dummyfying of a variable, but I have not been able to get the result I'm looking for. I'm sure there must be an easy solution for it, but was not able to find it.

My data set that looks like this:

| TM_ID | APPLICATION_YEAR | EXPIRATION | DURATION | NICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1870 | 1902 | 32 | CLASE 34 |
| 6 | 1870 | 1891 | 21 | CLASE 32 |
| 19 | 1902 | 1943 | 41 | CLASE 34 |
| 19 | 1902 | 1943 | 41 | CLASE 16 |
| 20 | 1876 | 1881 | 5 | CLASE 34 |
| 21 | 1876 | 1877 | 12 | CLASE 34 |
| 70 | 1877 | 1902 | 25 | CLASE 16 |
| 70 | 1877 | 1902 | 25 | CLASE 34 |

and I would like to dummyfy the column NICE to obtain one row per TM_ID and ones in the columns representing each of the levels in column NICE.

I tried with dummyVars(); it created one dummy for each level but there were still more than one observation per TM_ID. I tried as well with dcast() or pivot_wider(), but I have not been able to achieve what I need. It should look like this:

| TM_ID | APPLICATION_YEAR | EXPIRATION | DURATION | CLASE 16 | CLASE 32 | CLASE 34 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1870 | 1902 | 32 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 1870 | 1891 | 21 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 19 | 1902 | 1943 | 41 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 20 | 1876 | 1881 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 21 | 1876 | 1877 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 70 | 1877 | 1902 | 25 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Were there is one only observation per ID and 1s en each of the corresponding columns of NICE levels.

The only way I found to do this is one-hot encoding first with dummyVars(), and then group_by() and mutate(), like:

```
group_by(TM_ID) %>%
mutate(NICE_1 = sum(NICE.1), NICE_10 = sum(NICE.10), NICE_11 = sum(NICE.11)......
```

But the problem with this solution is that I had to type each argument in the mutate, one per dummy (level of the original variable). What if there were hundreds of levels?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `pivot_wider` to get the data in wide format and use `values_fn = length` to dummify the `NICE` column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

res <- df %>%
  arrange(NICE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = NICE, values_from = NICE, 
              values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)

res

#  TM_ID APPLICATION_YEAR EXPIRATION DURATION `CLASE 16` `CLASE 32` `CLASE 34`
#  <int>            <int>      <int>    <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
#1    19             1902       1943       41          1          0          1
#2    70             1877       1902       25          1          0          1
#3     6             1870       1891       21          0          1          0
#4     5             1870       1902       32          0          0          1
#5    20             1876       1881        5          0          0          1
#6    21             1876       1877       12          0          0          1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(TM_ID = c(5L, 6L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 70L, 70L
), APPLICATION_YEAR = c(1870L, 1870L, 1902L, 1902L, 1876L, 1876L, 
1877L, 1877L), EXPIRATION = c(1902L, 1891L, 1943L, 1943L, 1881L, 
1877L, 1902L, 1902L), DURATION = c(32L, 21L, 41L, 41L, 5L, 12L, 
25L, 25L), NICE = c("CLASE 34", "CLASE 32", "CLASE 34", "CLASE 16", 
"CLASE 34", "CLASE 34", "CLASE 16", "CLASE 34")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df)[order(NICE)], ... ~ NICE, value.var = 'NICE', length)
   TM_ID APPLICATION_YEAR EXPIRATION DURATION CLASE 16 CLASE 32 CLASE 34
1:     5             1870       1902       32        0        0        1
2:     6             1870       1891       21        0        1        0
3:    19             1902       1943       41        1        0        1
4:    20             1876       1881        5        0        0        1
5:    21             1876       1877       12        0        0        1
6:    70             1877       1902       25        1        0        1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(TM_ID = c(5L, 6L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 70L, 70L
), APPLICATION_YEAR = c(1870L, 1870L, 1902L, 1902L, 1876L, 1876L, 
1877L, 1877L), EXPIRATION = c(1902L, 1891L, 1943L, 1943L, 1881L, 
1877L, 1902L, 1902L), DURATION = c(32L, 21L, 41L, 41L, 5L, 12L, 
25L, 25L), NICE = c("CLASE 34", "CLASE 32", "CLASE 34", "CLASE 16", 
"CLASE 34", "CLASE 34", "CLASE 16", "CLASE 34")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```